# what is the proper jquery selector of a list within one of the div within a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use JQuery for the only one ul list within my HTML. I cannot figure out what is the proper JQuery Selector for this ul list. Below is my HTML and Javascript Code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //initial
    $('#content').load('content/index.php');
});
    //handle menu clicks 
    $('#Kevin li a').click(function(){
        alert("hi");
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel= stylesheet>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="css/bootstrap.css"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main_IEEE.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="uci_website.js"></script>     
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target= ".navHeaderCollapse">
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class= "nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="Kevin">
                        <li class = "active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Membership Application</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="text">
                    <h1><a href="https://www.ieee.org/index.html"><img src="ieee_mb_white.png"></a></h1>
                        <p>UCIrvine Student Chapter</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span2">
                        <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1asOLuwicpKd90KVlX6e9VrEpLGZk9DQ1LlItgblvEvA/pub?embedded=true" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>       
    </body>
</html>
```

What would be the proper way to attribute the Jquery selector? Thanks!

Comment: Your selector looks good.

Comment: what is exactly wrong with your code? please clarify more on what you want.

Comment: you closed document.ready twice `});`, once before the comment `//handle menu clicks` and the other at the end of your js

Answer (score 2):

You closed line no:4 **});**  "SyntaxError"
 Update your jQuery function like the below:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    //initial
    $('#content').load('content/index.php');
   //handle menu clicks 
    $('#Kevin li a').click(function(){
        alert("hi");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#Kevin li a').click(function(){
        alert("hi");
    });
});
```

I think you have to use it direct 
if it is not working on id you try to use class 
like.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.kevin li a').click(function(){
        alert("hi");
    });
});
```

and use class in a ul tag